# RemoveAll and AppendChild afterwards fails?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to remove all childs, and then append a new child instead:

```
$xml.Data.RemoveAll()
$xml.Data.appendChild( ... )
```

But then I get

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a
>   method named 'appendChild'.

As if the deletion actaully turned the `XmlNode` into a `System.String` object.

How can I add child nodes to the empty `$xml.Data` node?

Comment: `$Data=$xml.Data; $Data.RemoveAll(); $Data.appendChild( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the syntax of accessing data through dots returns a string if there are no children or attributes on the xml node.

However the node itself can be accessed through `$xml.SelectSingleNode` even if it's empty:

```
$xml.Data.RemoveAll()
$xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data").appendChild( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element has no children and no attributes then PowerShell evaluates it as a string. This is what is happening to the "Data" element in your example after calling `RemoveAll()`.

I have no idea why PowerShell does this, or how to stop it. As a workaround, I suggest forcing Powershell to treat "Data" as an element by adding a temporary attribute. After adding new child elements, remove the temporary attribute. For example:

```
#Set-up
$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml("<Data><A1/><A2><B1/><B2/></A2></Data>")
$xml.Data.RemoveAll()

#Add a temporary attribute to "Data"
$temporaryAttribute = $xml.CreateAttribute("temp")
$xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data").attributes.append($temporaryAttribute) | out-null

#Add new children
$newChild = $xml.CreateElement("NewChild")
$xml.Data.appendChild($newChild) | out-null
#Add next new child etc. etc.

#When done, remove the temporary attribute
$xml.Data.Attributes.Remove($temporaryAttribute) | out-null

#View the result
$xml.OuterXml
```